# Building circled items in different colours

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

I intent to build items exactly as the ones in the following code but filled with a different colour in the circle and in the font on each appearance (e.g. the first one red with "1" in white and the second green with "2" in brown). How can I do it? Thanks.

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}


\mode<presentation>
{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}

\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\itemnum}[1]{%
\setcounter{enumi}{#1}\usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
These are my items~{\itemnum{1}} and~{\itemnum{2}}  ...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome! Who decides the colors? Should it cycle through a list? Should it choose randomly? Should it be supplied by the user (in an optional or mandatory argument)? Should it be dependent on a style/key? Should they adhere to some kind of beamer color template?

Comment: All the colors should be given by the user in each appearance and I don't want to use ```\begin{enumerate}... \end{enumerate}``` (because they will be used along text). In the above post I gave as example red, white, green and brown, but it must be a command such that I'm free to use other colors if I wish. And I want something independent of templates or everything else. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the the template `enumerate item` uses the color settings of `item projected` you can use it to adjust the colors of both the circle (`bg`) as well as the text (`fg`).

I've added `\unskip` and `\unbreak` to adjust the horizontal spacing (the space before it is too much in my opinion) and to suppress a linebreak.

### Code

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}
\mode<article>{ % only for the article version
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}
\mode<presentation>{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}
\setbeamercovered{dynamic}
\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]
\newcommand{\itemnum}[2][]{{% extra {} to keep changes local
  \setbeamercolor{item projected}{#1}%
  \setcounter{enumi}{#2}%
  \unskip\nobreak % no linebreak and no space before it
  \usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}%
}}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
These are my items \itemnum[bg=red,   fg=white]{1}
               and \itemnum[fg=brown, bg=green]{2} \dots
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You already got the perfect answer to your question, but just as an alternative: here a solution using the `circledsteps` package

```
\documentclass[10pt,xcolor={dvipsnames,table}]{beamer}

\mode<article> % only for the article version
{
  \usepackage{fullpage}
  \usepackage{hyperref}
}


\mode<presentation>
{
  %\setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=red!10,top=blue!10]
  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  \usefonttheme{serif}
  \usecolortheme{crane}
}

\usepackage{tikz}

\setbeamercovered{dynamic}

\usepackage{circledsteps}

\setbeamertemplate{items}[circle]

\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\newcommand{\itemnum}[1]{%
\setcounter{enumi}{#1}\usebeamertemplate{enumerate item}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
These are my items~{\footnotesize\Circled[inner color=white,fill color=red,outer color=red]{1}} and~{\footnotesize\Circled[inner color=lightgray,fill color=green,outer color=green]{2}}  ...
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]